# Which java technology is used to develop android apps?

Tags: java, android

Can I develop it on J2SE or J2ME is important?

Answer (score 6):

No. Dalvik uses [its own class libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29#Class_library).

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't use JavaME or JavaSE. It doesn't run on a JVM, but on Dalvik, a specific virtual machine.

Though, the Android framework is very similar to JavaSE, apart from graphical and security libraries, which are specific. And all OpenGL ES related classes are the same as in JavaME.

Answer (score 0):

J2SE works and android SDK.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html